# Why include /dev/null in makefile?

Tags: linux, makefile, include, dev-null

I ran across a line in a makefile. The line was:

```
-include $(wildcard makefile.mk) /dev/null
```

I don't understand the purpose of the /dev/null in the include line. Is it intentional or is it a mistake? Perhaps they intended to send the output there? I'm still rather new to makefiles, can someone help me make sense of this?

Comment: It's probably used to guarantee there is at least one file specified in case the rest of line expands to nothing.

Comment: @MarkSetchell could you put that as answer? Perhaps expanding on it too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is used to ensure that, even if the wildcard expands to nothing at all, the `include` will result in at least one file - /dev/null. Maybe I can explain it like this... imagine you had a hypothetical compilation like this

```
INCLUDES=$(wildcard /usr/inc*)
CC -I INCLUDES prog.c -o prog
```

If your (admittedly strange) environment didn't have anything in /usr/include, your compilation command would expand to

```
CC -I prog.c -o prog
```

which is likely to give an error. So the `/dev/null` addition would maybe avoid that.

I am not saying it is necessary, I am just saying I think that is maybe its purpose. It is similar to when programmers use

```
grep pattern file /dev/null
```

rather than the more modern

```
grep -H pattern file
```

because it is a file that will definitely exist, and as such `grep` will receive two files as arguments and will therefore tell you the name of the file it found the pattern in - exactly as if you had specified `-H`.

Another example is the `format` command on Solaris. It gives you a lovely list of all the attached disks, but then sits there hanging till you choose one - which us not ideal if you want to parse the list from a script. Here again, you can use /dev/null and it will list the disks and exit if you do

```
format < /dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

It's totally unecessary; `include` doesn't do anything if there aren't any filenames specified.

Comment: So the /dev/null addition is supposed to cover the case of no results, is this good and/or typical coding standard? or is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: No, there's no reason to do it at all.